# In CQRS (event-sourced), do you need a global sequence counter in the event store?

Tags: domain-driven-design, cqrs

In trying to get my head around CQRS (and DDD in general) I have come across situations when two events occur on different aggregates but the order of them has domain meaning.  If so then they could happen so close together that a timestamp (as used by the sample implementations I have seen) cannot differentiate them, meaning the event store doesn't contain a 'complete' representation of the domain as there is ambiguity over the order in which events occurred.

As an example, the domain could fire a `CustomerCreatedEvent` which applies to the `Customer` aggregate, and then a `CustomerAssignedToAgent` event on the `Agent` aggregate.  The `CustomerAssignedToAgent` event doesn't make sense if it occurs before the `CustomerCreatedEvent`, but typically both of these might be fired as a result of one operation which makes it likely that the timestamps would effectively be the same.

So am I just modelling things badly?  Should there ever be a situation where the sequence of events across different aggregates is important?  Or should you keep a global sequence number on your event store, so that you can identify the exact sequence in which events occurred?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In general it is bad idea to enforce global order. Aggregates are meant to form ACID-semantics boundaries.

This means that two aggregates should not be updated in one transaction and there is no other means of enforcing global order.

In your case it could make sense that along with creating CustomerCreatedEvent Customer should send a message to Agent aggregate telling it to assign itself. Generally inter-aggregate communication should be done via messaging.

Comment: Thanks Szymon, I thought that was the most likely case!

Comment: I have read the same lots of times, but... when you use your EventStore as queue to consume events from other bounded contexts, or even for the same BC in which they are generated, how can you be sure that you get them in order? you don't need them in a very strict order, but you at least need to be able to consume them from a given offset.

Answer (score 10):

I also found [this post by Greg Young](http://tech.groups.yahoo.com/group/domaindrivendesign/message/18453) on the domaindrivendesign yahoo list:

> Order is only assured per a handler within an aggregate root boundary.
>
> There is no assurance of order between handlers or between aggregates.
>
> Trying to provide those things leads to the dark side.